# win10 try to look for a solution of the problems when I run this

Tags: c++, windows

when I run it the window crash and Win10 try to look for a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    int num1, num2, valoreMedio;

    printf("inserire primo numero:");
    scanf("%d", num1);
    printf("inserire secondo numero:");
    scanf("%d", num2);

    if(num1==num2){
        printf("%d", num1);
    }else{
        valoreMedio=(num1+num2)/2;
        printf("il valore medio e': %d", valoreMedio);
    }
}
```

if the numbers inserted are equal it print one of them, while if they are different it print the average.

Comment: Please post code that compiles. This is not valid C++. At most you are using an outdated C dialect.

Answer (score -1):

Try scanf_s instead of scanf , it should help.

Comment: [Error]'scanf_s' wasn't declared in this scope